# Mail is downloading forever

Tags: mail.app, high-sierra

I noticed that I hadn't received any new mail in my Gmail account in Mail.app in the last three days. It is being received fine on my iPhone and iPad, as well as my PC.

When I look at the Activity Window, it says it is downloading message 112,500 of 112,525. It sits there for a while, then it starts downloading those last 25. But as it starts, the other number jumps up another 1000, so now I'm on (say)v 112,520 of 113,250. This has been going on for three days.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. How many e-mails do you have in Gmail (check through browser)? 2. In Mail app open `Window -> Connection Doctor`, check status and details of Google account connection. Then click `Show details` and see what's going on there. Also you may may want to check `Log Connection Activity` and check logs then.

Comment: I have 10,909 messages in total in GMail. All accounts have green circles in Doctor and Diagnostics is empty.

Comment: Try taking all your account offline and then back online. And also try rebuilding your mailbox.